# Aligning an element to the right using XSL-FO, Apache FOP

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using XSL-FO with Apache FOP to take a sexy looking XML file and output it as a PDF, however I'm having a really basic problem trying to get a particular bit of information (the address) to be positioned from the right of the page, I can force it over to the right by increasing the `left` attribute, but if I change my page size, orientation or margins this will immediately be useless.

Below is the code for the XSL, note the comment on line 23.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages"
                        page-height="297mm"
                        page-width="210mm"
                        margin-top="1cm" 
                        margin-bottom="1cm"
                        margin-left="1cm" 
                        margin-right="1cm" >
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="5cm" margin-bottom="1.1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="1cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent="5mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="default-sequence">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="all-pages"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-sequence">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before" font-size="10pt" font-family="Helvetica" >
                    <!-- HERE'S MY PROBLEM, THE RIGHT ATTRIBUTE ISN'T BEHAVING ITSELF -->
                    <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" right="4cm" top="1cm" width="6cm"  border-style="solid" border-width="1mm"  >
                        <fo:list-block >
                            <fo:list-item>
                                <fo:list-item-label>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:list-item-label>
                                <fo:list-item-body>
                                    <fo:block>ABC</fo:block>
                                </fo:list-item-body>
                            </fo:list-item>
                            <fo:list-item>
                                <fo:list-item-label>
                                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                                </fo:list-item-label>
                                <fo:list-item-body>
                                    <fo:block>123</fo:block>
                                </fo:list-item-body>
                            </fo:list-item>
                        </fo:list-block>
                    </fo:block-container>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" padding-top="2pt" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(192,192,192)" font-size="10pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                </fo:static-content>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="10pt" font-family="Helvetica">
                    <fo:block></fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And as you can see by this screenshot the element isn't positioning correctly:

[image]

Any one know know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bugger, looked at the [FOP changelog](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/changes.html) and the two years between versions 0.95 and 1.0 made me think whether it was a bug, downloaded the new binaries and it's now positioning my element from the right.